# How to prevent "bigger text" (font scaling) on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Ive been looking around to find an answer, but all I can find is related to web scripting, so...

We are testing an app, and it seems that one user had "increased text size (from phone settings)," but the only texts that are actually increased are the cells of tableviews? I don't understand why the text are not increased in any other place (but I thank the coding god), since it is indeed increased in tableviews?
Anyway, can someone help me on how to fix this so that my tableviews hold a static font size?

Comment: So for visually impaired users, you want to insure they cannot read the apps text?

Comment: Wondering why did I get a down vote?

Comment: @DavidH As I said in my previous comment, I had the same comment as you to the designer. Regardless, we can't always have the final word when developing for someone else:/

Comment: You probably got voted down because this is such a horrible thing to do. Your designer should allow all text to vary in size, otherwise switch to Android (IMHO).

Comment: @DavidH No worries. (btw, it is made on both android and iOS )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the developers set defined size for most of the labels. They should use system size to make it work properly.

Comment: is system size based on the scaling factor? What I mean is, if I have an amount of users that didn't enable "bigger text", can the text size be influenced by other factors that I might not account for?

Comment: @DevilInDisguise I don't fully understand this question. If your user didn't enable bigger text then the text should be of standard size. I can't recall any other factor, which influences it. Does it answer your question?

Comment: it does. I suppose using system size, and then setting max size in Xcode would be the right way to go.